# beautifulSoup parsing tag table HTML, especially colspan and rowspan

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, html-table

I want to ask about parsing a value colspan and rowspan from `<table>`.
for example like this:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" width="50%">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" rowspan="2" colspan="1" align="center">NO<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" rowspan="1" colspan="3" align="center">NAMA<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" rowspan="1" colspan="2" align="center">TELEPON<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" rowspan="2" colspan="1" align="center">KODE<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">DEPAN<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">TENGAH<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">BELAKANG<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">KODE<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">NO TLP<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">1<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Ani<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Tiara<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Ramadika<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">021<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">8466729<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">17412<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">2<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Dia<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Andari<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Putri<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">022<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">5930290<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">18291<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">3<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Rangga<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Dimas<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Putra<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">023<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">8349829<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">13901<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center">4<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Niko<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Reza<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">Anggara<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">024<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">4284982<br>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="center">21211<br>
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>  
</table>
```

I use python for HTML parsing, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
t = soup.find("table")
dat = [ map(str, row.findAll('td', { 'rowspan' })) for row in t.findAll("tr") ]
print dat[1]
```

But still, I am really confused how to get the value of `colspan`.

I've already got the parsing tag table, but I don't know how to get the value of the `colspan` attribute. I've tried using a regex, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = open("colspan_rowspan.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

# select all td children of tr that have both colspan & rowspan
tags = soup.select('tr td[colspan,rowspan]')

# print out the values, for example:
print [(td['colspan'], td['rowspan']) for tags]

# will return [('1', '2'), ('3', '1'), ('2', '1'), ('1', '2')]
```

Comment: i've tried the code from you, but i don't know why i can't run (F5) the code? please give me a clue,why the code doesn't work? i use python 2.7, thank you sir

Comment: is there an error, and if, what is it? the more information you provide about what you're doing and your environment, the easier it is to help you out.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to parse tables with colspan and rowspan is to use nodejs with cheerio and cheerio-tableparser plugin.

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    cheerioTableparser = require('cheerio-tableparser'),
    fs = require('fs');

var text = fs.readFileSync("colspan_rowspan.html", 'utf8');
$ = cheerio.load(text);
cheerioTableparser($);

data = $("table").parsetable(true, true, true);
console.log(data);

//data = > 
//[ [ 'NO', 'NO', '1', '2', '3', '4' ],
//  [ 'NAMA', 'DEPAN', 'Ani', 'Dia', 'Rangga', 'Niko' ],
//  [ 'NAMA', 'TENGAH', 'Tiara', 'Andari', 'Dimas', 'Reza' ],
//  [ 'NAMA', 'BELAKANG', 'Ramadika', 'Putri', 'Putra', 'Anggara' ],
//  [ 'TELEPON', 'KODE', '021', '022', '023', '024' ],
//  [ 'TELEPON', 'NO TLP', '8466729', '5930290', '8349829', '4284982' ],
//  [ 'KODE', 'KODE', '17412', '18291', '13901', '21211' ] ]
```

Result will be array of columns. All merged by colspan and rowspan cells will have same values in array.

Comment: OP seems to have asked for a Python solution. The above does not seem to be a Python solution.